# X-Requested-With header not set in jquery ajaxForm plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using the [jQuery ajaxForms plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to make an ajax submit to my CakePHP app.

Cake's RequestHandler detects ajax requests by looking at the "X-Requested-With" header, but the forms plugin does not seem to set it. Or jQuery does not set it when using the plugin.

I've tried several things,

in the main onload function i added:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"}
});
```

In the plugin code I added this right before the actual ajax call:

```
options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest");
};
```

Making a regular ajax call, does set the header...

Can anyone tell me what's going on or most important, how can I fix this?

Comment: jQuery will add the X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest header on ajax calls and the ajaxForms plugin uses jquerys ajax function to do ajax calls. The only time I could see it not getting sent is if you are doing a file upload with the ajaxForms plugin

Comment: it is idd a multipart form... why does it do this, and can this be fixed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@Nicky De Maeyer's answer to his own question

Actually you don't need to do this yourself (appending a hidden input field).

AFAIK you can just pass such data to ajaxForms plugin in the options object

```
$('#myForm1').ajaxForm({data:{"X_REQUESTED_WITH":"XMLHttpRequest"}});
```

Should automagically (in the hidden iframe file upload case) append such an input to your form on submission

```
<input type="hidden" name="X_REQUESTED_WITH" value="XMLHttpRequest" />
```

Comment: Just as a side not for people using ASP.NET MVC. MVC is case sensitive and will not recognise the parameter unless the name is "X-Requested-With".

Answer (score 3):

New development:

As of now, the [jquery.form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm) now supports multipart (including file) Uploads very well , in a cross-browser compatible way, and sets the X-Requested-With header.  I was having this problem with an older version of jquery.form and the upgrade to 3.02 fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

Going from petersendidit's comment, I went searching for ajax/file upload questions.

there's an interesting question on it on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-to-upload-file-jquery) stating it is not possible, only through a hack with an iFrame. So no actual ajax call is made...

since my form is a multipart with a file upload, the plugin uses the iFrametechnique instead of the regular ajax call...

To solve this to know this should resemble an ajax call i'll add a hidden input field on the multipart forms...

Comment: Or just add `xhr.setRequestHeader("X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest");`

Answer (score 0):

I just had to deal with an issue today that was similar to this and came up with a different solution.  The issue came up with Chrome, Safari, and IE where the header (which I was checking in PHP via `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'`) wasn't matching.

As it was outlined in a previous answer, when using jQuery ajax functions, this header will be already set by jQuery.

In said browsers above, when using:

```
options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest");
};
```

Those browsers (not Firefox) would append that to the header.  So in actuality, the header was set as:  'XMLHttpRequest, XMLHttpRequest'

Bottom line, don't set this header when using jquery AJAX functions.  Hopefully that solves someones headache.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be lack of support for file uploads in older versions of the plugin.  When I removed the file inputs, the problem went away.